# Converting tz naive datetime to tz aware jumps from 0 minutes to 58

Tags: python, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

When I'm converting unaware `datetime` to aware, it does a weird thing. It adds 58 minutes.

```py
_datetime = datetime.combine(_date,_time)
print(_datetime)
datetime_tz = _datetime.replace(tzinfo='Europe/Bratislava')
print(_datetime_tz)
```

> 2020-02-02 12:45:00
>   2020-02-02 12:45:00+00:58

Do you know why and how to make it work?

Comment: That's because you're using `replace` instead of pytz's `localize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly use a timezone object from `pytz`, you must use the `localize` function.

```
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Bratislava')
>>> _datetime = datetime.combine(_date,_time)
>>> print(_datetime)
2020-02-02 12:45:00
>>> _datetime_tz = tz.localize(_datetime)
>>> print(_datetime_tz)
2020-02-02 12:45:00+01:00
```

If you don't do this, the timezone object is in an invalid state because it doesn't have a chance to adjust for the date.